# Can't assign an string to an array element inside my Swift function

Tags: swift

Both assignment lines in the code below give me this error:

> '@|value $T5' is not identical to 'String'

```
   func PrintShoppingList(myList: Array<String>)
    {
        println(myList)
        var cabbage = "cabbage"
        let fish:String = "fish"
        myList[0] = cabbage
        myList[1] = fish
    }
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parameters are constants by default and you cannot mutate them. You can change them to `var`, but this will be a copy of array.

```
func PrintShoppingList(var myList: Array<String>)
{
    println(myList)
    var cabbage = "cabbage"
    let fish:String = "fish"
    myList[0] = cabbage
    myList[1] = fish
}
```

You can also use `inout` parameter to mutate original value, but remember that array length cannot be extended by superscript, so `myList[1] = fish` will crash in this case.

```
func PrintShoppingList(inout myList: Array<String>)
{
    println(myList)
    var cabbage = "cabbage"
    let fish:String = "fish"
    myList[0] = cabbage
    myList.append(fish)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that the argument passed to function is by default set as constant and is immutable. So you need to declared it as var to be able to mutate it.

```
func PrintShoppingList(var myList: Array<String>)
{
    println(myList)
    var cabbage = "cabbage"
    let fish:String = "fish"
    myList[0] = cabbage
    myList[1] = fish
    print(myList)
}
```

Your app might crash if you pass array with less than 2 elements, since you are accessing **myList[0]** and **myList[1]**. So, make sure that your array has at least to elements to pass array to this method.

Comment: That's right - use += or .append(). See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/CollectionTypes.html